# Quoting square brackets in an Asciidoctor link description

Tags: quoting, asciidoctor

I am writing a release guide in Asciidoctor for a project I am contributing.

The document contains a link and the intended link description should contain placeholes like `[variable]`. As Asciidoctor alsi uses square brackets to enclose the link description I quoted my square brackets. But the result is not the indended one.

Here is an simplified example of my attempt:

```
Here comes the problem!

https://dist.apache.org/[https://dist.apache.org/repos/\[version\]\[project\]^].
```

Asciidoctor (version 1.5.6.1) renders the link as `https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/tamaya/\[version]/\[project]`. But I expected `https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/tamaya/[version]/\[project]`as result.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, using the decimal HTML Entity code is the solution. This should work for both HTML and PDF. For your case:

- [left square bracket: [](http://graphemica.com/%5B)
- [right square bracket ]](http://graphemica.com/%5D)

I would write:

```
Here comes the problem!

https://dist.apache.org/[https://dist.apache.org/repos/&#91;version&#93;&#91;project&#93;^].
```

If you use the entities a lot, you can use variables:

```
:left_sb: &#91;
:rigth_sb: &#93;

Here comes the problem!

https://dist.apache.org/[https://dist.apache.org/repos/{left_sb}version{rigth_sb}{left_sb}project{rigth_sb}^].
```